# How to reference cell always in the same column, but immediately above a border that can move vertically?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to figure out how to specifically reference cells just above a lower border of several Excel sheets within the same workbook, referencing them in the `"ThisWorkbook"` object.

I am dealing with an Excel workbook that begins as 3 sheets, and then generates 17 more by pulling data from a database. The data varies, and so the number of rows within the sheets varies from trial to trial. The cells I am trying to reference are found within these generated sheets. The only thing consistent about the cells I wish to reference is that they are in the same column and they will always be just above the generated border.

The code I want to implement looks something like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
If WorksheetFunction.CountA( _
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1,A2,A3,A5,A5, A6")) < 3 Then MsgBox "Workbook will not be saved unless" & vbCrLf &  "All required signatures have been recorded.", "Missing info"
```

Cancel = True
End If
End Sub

What I want to do is to not allow the file to save unless all of the signature locations have some contents. I really have no idea about the syntax necessary to make this work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here are links to a few pictures of the cells I am trying to reference and the border around them.

Comment: You need to share screenshot of what your Border looks like and the Data

Comment: Do you have access to the code that's generating the other sheets? If so, I would modify that code to create a sheet-level named range. Then in your Before_Save, you can refer to that named range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a loop down the column, or from the bottom up, using a check on the bottom border of the cells, such that:

```
For i = lr to 2 Step -1 'lr is last row
    If Cells(i,1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
        TargetRow = i
        Exit for
    End If
Next i
Debug.Print TargetRow
```

You may want to adjust to `weight` depending on your border, or if other borders exist that you want to exclude.

You can then use `TargetRow` for your other code.

---

**Edit1:**

Sheet looping:

```
For each ws in Workbook.Worksheets
    For i = lr to 2 Step -1 'lr is last row
        If Cells(i,1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle <> xlLineStyleNone Then
            TargetRow = i
            Exit for
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print TargetRow
    If TargetRow > 0 Then
        'Do something with TargetRow
    End If
    TargetRow = 0 'Reset before next sheet as to not mess anything up
Next ws
```

Comment: That's really helpful thanks! Would I just have to manually reenter code this for every individual sheet or is there a way that I could get it to run for every sheet simultaneously?

Comment: @Andrew you could set this up to loop through the sheets as well.  The above code would be nested inside a `for each ws in Workbook.Worksheets  //  Next ws`.  It may be appropriate to ensure that `TargetRow = 0` before you move to the next sheet.

Comment: @Andrew if this has answered your question, please mark the check for *Answered* to the left of the post, so this is listed appropriately in the Questions search

Comment: So once the rows for each sheet are all stored in an array, how can I put them into the code I had above to designate the cells which I want to check for content in?

Comment: @Andrew I think we're getting outside of the scope of your original question  with your last comment on my Answer.  I will add a little bit more in comment here, but will say that you may want to open up another question after you've tried utilizing the above code, which should fit the bill for the original question... In the code I provided, I use column 1 (A) to check for line styling and determine `TargetRow`; you can use `ws.Cells(TargetRow,1)` to reference the exact cell that was looked at, or even a range of cells such that:  `ws.Range(ws.Cells(Start,1),ws.Cells(TargetRow,1))`.